# How to avoid performance warning for unique_ptr check in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unique-ptr

This code:

```
    unique_ptr<int> a;
    if (a) {
        cout << "ASSIGNED" << endl;
    }
```

and even this code:

```
    unique_ptr<int> a;
    if (static_cast<bool>(a)) {
        cout << "ASSIGNED" << endl;
    }
```

cause this warning:

```
warning C4800: 'void (__cdecl *)(std::_Bool_struct<_Ty> &)' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
with
[
    _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int>
]
```

in Visual Studio 2012 on warning level 3. After the first comments I found out that it only happens if common language runtime support /clr is switched on. How should I avoid it?

```
if (a.get() != nullptr)
```

should work, but I think that is not how unique_ptr was designed, was it?

Comment: I have VS2013, but it doesn't give me such warning!

Comment: Builds with no warning in Visual Studio 2010 with level warning set to "/W4"...

Comment: I am compiling on /W3 (added to post)

Comment: No need for `.get()`! `if (a != nullptr)` works.

Comment: @billz, Johan: I just found that /clr must be switched on to receive the warning. Added to post.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's an acceptable solution IMO. I wasn't aware != is overloaded for nullptr_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use directly

```
if (a != nullptr)
```

Comment: noloader's answer is also valid I guess, but I prefer this solution instead of the ugly double exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually clear the performance warning on Visual Studio with `!!`:

```
unique_ptr<int> a;
if (!!a) {
    cout << "ASSIGNED" << endl;
}
```

I read about it on Michael Howard's blog a long time ago, but I don't have a reference. He was talking about clean compiles and working with the compiler instead of turning off warnings.